# Comparing lists of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I've have read various questions but nothing I have found quite matches this scenario and I can't get it round my head.

I want to compare 2 lists of dictionaries. I don't want to check the individual key value pairs, I want to check the whole dictionary against the other but the gotcha is that one of the dictionaries in one list has an extra item 'id' which the other list doesn't so I don't need to compare that.

status_code and desc are not unique

just desc could change but as far as I'm concerned the whole thing has then changed.

Sample data:

```
data_db = [
    { "id": 1, "status_code": 2, "desc": "Description sample1" },
    { "id": 2, "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample2" },
    { "id": 3, "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" },
    { "id": 4, "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample4" }
]

data_api = [
    { "status_code": 1, "desc": "Description sample5" },
    { "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample6" },
    { "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" }
]
```

Expected output:

```
missing_from_db = [
     { "status_code": 1, "desc": "Description sample4" },
     { "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample6" } # because in data_db it desc is different
]

missing_from_api = [1,2,4] # This can just be the ids from data_db
```

I hope this makes sense (as it's confusing enough to me!).

Code wise I've not come up with anything remotely close or useful. Nearest thought I've had is reformatting data_db to this:

```
data_db = [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "data": { "status_code": 2, "desc": "Description sample1" }
    },
    { 
        "id": 2, 
        "data": { "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample2" }
    },
    { 
        "id": 3, 
        "data": { "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" }
    },
    { 
        "id": 4, 
        "data": { "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample4" }
    }
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Go with the reformatted `data_db`.

Comment: Writing out the question actually helped me get my head around it a lot and on to that thought. Shall try that in future when getting stuck/confused on something!

Comment: The same thing has happened to me many times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reformatting your `data_db` should work:

```
data_db = [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "data": { "status_code": 2, "desc": "Description sample1" }
    },
    { 
        "id": 2, 
        "data": { "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample2" }
    },
    { 
        "id": 3, 
        "data": { "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" }
    },
    { 
        "id": 4, 
        "data": { "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample4" }
    }
]

data_api = [
    { "status_code": 1, "desc": "Description sample5" },
    { "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample6" },
    { "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" }
]

#   checking the dicts in data_api against the 'data' sub-dicts in data_db
missing_from_db = [d for d in data_api if d not in [x['data'] for x in data_db]]

#   using similar comprehension to extract the 'id' vals of the 'data' in data_db which aren't in data_api
missing_from_api = [d['id'] for d in data_db if d['data'] not in data_api]
```

Results:

```
print missing_from_db

[{'status_code': 1, 'desc': 'Description sample5'}, 
 {'status_code': 4, 'desc': 'Description sample6'}]

print missing_from_api

[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you. Spot on, short and sweet/pythonic!

Comment: Cheers. There's a way to do it with your original data structure, too, but you'd need additional function or lambda function and i couldn't wrap my head around that part of it, either.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a nice solution and it relies on the particular structure you have, but it works:

```
data_db = [
    { "id": 1, "status_code": 2, "desc": "Description sample1" },
    { "id": 2, "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample2" },
    { "id": 3, "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" },
    { "id": 4, "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample4" }
]

data_api = [
    { "status_code": 1, "desc": "Description sample5" },
    { "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample6" },
    { "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" }
]

lst = []
for dct in data_api:
    for dct2 in data_db:
        if all(dct[key] == dct2[key] for key in dct):
            break
    else:
        lst.append(dct)

lst2 = []
for dct2 in data_db:
    for dct in data_api:
        if all(dct[key] == dct2[key] for key in dct):
            break
    else:
        lst2.append(dct2["id"])

print(lst)
print(lst2)
```

Answer (score 0):

will this help

```
def find_missing(data1,data2):
    missig_from_data = list()
    for i in range(0,len(data2)):
        status = False
        dec = False
        for j in range(0,len(data1)):
            if data2[i]['status_code'] == data1[j]['status_code']:
                status = True
                if data2[i]['desc'] == data1[j]['desc']:
                    dec = True
        if (status == False and dec==False) or (status == True and dec==False) or (status == False and dec==True):
            missig_from_data.append(data2[i])

    return missig_from_data

data_db = [
    { "id": 1, "status_code": 2, "desc": "Description sample1" },
    { "id": 2, "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample2" },
    { "id": 3, "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" },
    { "id": 4, "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample4" }
]

data_api = [
    { "status_code": 1, "desc": "Description sample5" },
    { "status_code": 4, "desc": "Description sample6" },
    { "status_code": 5, "desc": "Description sample3" }
]

missig_from_data_db = find_missing(data_db,data_api)
missing_from_api = find_missing(data_api,data_db)
missing_from_api_1 = list()

for i in range(0,len(missing_from_api)): missing_from_api_1.append(missing_from_api[i]['id'])

print missig_from_data_db
print missing_from_api_1
```

Output :

```
[{'status_code': 1, 'desc': 'Description sample5'}, {'status_code': 4, 'desc': 'Description sample6'}]
[1, 2, 4]
```